# How to add variable text in different files using for loop in bash script

Tags: bash, for-loop, variables

I'm trying to add some text to the end of a few files.
I have made a file, where I have 5 servername. Each servername corresponds to a separate config file. (**The path of these config files is not known**).

**I am using below code to get the file path,**

MyCode:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat serverlist-file | while read f; do find . -name "*$f*"; done);
do
echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
/data/servers/customer01/server01.cfg
/data/servers/customer01/server02.cfg
/data/servers/customer02/server03.cfg
/data/servers/customer03/server04.cfg
/data/servers/customer03/server05.cfg
```

**I am using below code to get the list of servers,**

MyCode:

```
#!/bin/bash
for j in $(cat serverlist-file);
do
echo $j
done
```

Output:

```
server01
server02
server03
server04
server05
```

Now I want to edit those config files and add text to it.

**I am using below code to add the required text:**

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat serverlist-file | while read f; do find . -name "*$f*"; done);
do
for j in $(cat serverlist-file);
do 
sed -i -e "\$a\
this\ is\ a\ config\ file\nfor\ $j" $i
done
done
```

**Expected Output:**

```
/data/servers/customer01/server01.cfg
this is a config file
for server01
/data/servers/customer01/server02.cfg
this is a config file
for server02
/data/servers/customer02/server03.cfg
this is a config file
for server03
/data/servers/customer03/server04.cfg
this is a config file
for server04
/data/servers/customer03/server05.cfg
this is a config file
for server05
```

Edit for a reply to @ShawnMilo:

I am trying to bulk add some config to some nagios config files, but not to all server config files.

So, searching with find . -name '*.config' isn't going to work, because then all the config files will get edited.
I only want specific files to get edited, just the servers from the serverlist-file.

Nagios configs need to have the hostname of the server in them, like:

```
define service {
use                             generic-service
host_name                       server01
service_description             SSH
contact_groups                   linux
check_command                check_something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an odd requirement. What are you actually trying to do?

In any case, this will do what was requested:

```
$ find . -name '*.config' | while read x; do echo $x; cat $x; echo; done
./data/servers/customer02/server03.config
default stuff here

./data/servers/customer03/server05.config
default stuff here

./data/servers/customer03/server04.config
default stuff here

./data/servers/customer01/server01.config
default stuff here

./data/servers/customer01/server02.config
default stuff here

$ find . -name '*.config' | while read x; do name=$(basename $x); echo -e "this is a config file\nfor ${name%%.*}" >> $x; done

$ find . -name '*.config' | while read x; do echo $x; cat $x; echo; done
./data/servers/customer02/server03.config
default stuff here
this is a config file
for server03

./data/servers/customer03/server05.config
default stuff here
this is a config file
for server05

./data/servers/customer03/server04.config
default stuff here
this is a config file
for server04

./data/servers/customer01/server01.config
default stuff here
this is a config file
for server01

./data/servers/customer01/server02.config
default stuff here
this is a config file
for server02
```

Comment: You can use the same `find` command to find all the files and add them to a text file. Then grep them against your list, then use that list.

```
find . -name '*.conf' > all_files.txt
grep -F -f serverlist all_files.txt > to_change.txt
```

Then use `to_change.txt` for the initial loop I describe instead of the output of the `find` command.